# Select element on Froala

Tags: javascript, jquery, selection, froala

This is my Froala editor :

```
var fe= new FroalaEditor("#edit", {
//rules
})
```

On cursor position, I able to find element with this code:

```
fe.selection.element();
```

How could I select and unselect it?